# How do we perform image compression in ASP.NET web-forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, image-compression

our portal maintains stores huge set of images in 4 folders

1. Projects
2. Campaigns
3. Films
4. Standard-images

We store the image path in a table and it's source in the aforementioned folders. What is the best practice for image compression?

Comment: Voted to close as primarily opinion based.

Comment: voted as too broad. also does not show research or attempt.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are in PNG format or a similar compressed format, you won't easily be able to compress them further.

The best solution for this kind of thing to run an image server that's capable of serving different size images, try looking at [Thumbor](http://thumbor.org/)

Thumbor has a bunch of neat things it can do to reduce the size of images.

Comment: so i need to compress the files manually right !! or is there any auto process

Comment: Thumbor is a piece of software that runs on a server. You would have to install and configure it. If you are looking for an instant solution to a problem, I'm not sure there is one. If you're looking for best practices, I don't see a problem with what you're doing.

Comment: i need image compressors like app-sprite,cause i don't any installation in my server .its already bit slow